# Convert innerHTML of a contenteditable text to normal string

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable

I use a content-editable element :

```
<span id="myinput" contenteditable="true">This is editable.</span>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myinput').innerHTML
```

to read its content from Javascript.

But the result is :

- `"blah    "` =>   `innerHTML = "blah &nbsp "`
- `"bonjour\n bonsoir"`  =>  `innerHTML = "bonjour<br>bonsoir"` (Firefox) and `innerHTML = "bonjour<div>bonsoir</div>"` (Chrome)
- maybe there are lots of other things that are translated into HTML...

**How to convert `innerHTML` into normal text?**

(i.e. in my 2 examples : `"blah    "` and `"bonjour\n bonsoir"`)

Comment: Apparently you need to process the content as a subtree of the document tree, extracting the text content and inserting line breaks according to some rules (that you need to define). The details depend in part on the intended *use* of the text.

Comment: This is partially solved : `innerText` works for all browsers except Firefox, for which I have created another specific question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893229/read-a-multiline-contenteditable-text-in-firefox

Answer (score 10):

Try using;

```
// for IE
document.getElementById('myinput').innerText

// for everyone else
document.getElementById('myinput').textContent
```

In terms of finding linebreaks, etc, consider;

```
el = document.getElementById('myinput');
var nodes = el.childNodes;
var text = '';

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {                        
    switch(nodes[i].nodeName) {
        case '#text'    : text = text + nodes[i].nodeValue;   break;
        case 'BR'       : text = text + '\n';      break;
    }
}
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Or just `var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;`

Comment: `.textContent` does not convert `<br>` to `\n`

Comment: `innerText` works on IE + Chrome, but not available on Firefox.
`textContent` doesn't work, because the line breaks are lost : `"bonjour\n bonsoir"` => `textContent = "bonjourbonsoir"`.  How to deal with this problem ?

Comment: updated answer, the only way i can see offhand is to determine the individual node type and handle appropriately. Probably could be done better with some regex wizadry

Comment: doesn't work for Chrome ;)   because it's not BR but <div>the new line</div> .... @EvilEpidemic

Comment: if you see Barts answer below he demonstrates a method on how to catch that case

Comment: Yup, that Bart's answer provides the correct solution (with [the tweak](https://gist.github.com/mkrauskopf/ec4eb73c27517ff9c6eb6a90c6e7241f)). Unfortunately, Firefox and Chrome (Edge uses now Chromium) handle newlines (`Enter` pressed by the user) differently and `innnerText` only **approximates** text content as the user sees it. And in Chrome such approximation doubles the number of new lines in most of the cases (bug in Chromium?). So we have to parse the text from HTML manually.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact this behaviour is not consistent in different browsers, you have to implement this yourself:

```
var convert = (function() {
    var convertElement = function(element) {
        switch(element.tagName) {
            case "BR": 
                return "\n";
            case "P": // fall through to DIV
            case "DIV": 
                return (element.previousSibling ? "\n" : "") 
                    + [].map.call(element.childNodes, convertElement).join("");
            default: 
                return element.textContent;
        }
    };

    return function(element) {
        return [].map.call(element.childNodes, convertElement).join("");
    };
})();
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/koyd8h59/1/

Of course you'll need to add your own code if you want to use `<h1>` and other block-level tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the same issue. I have to tweak it a bit further. When the user presses the `Enter` in Chrome, the engine enters `<div><br/><div>`. So that needs to be handled separately. See the [TypeScript Gist here](https://gist.github.com/mkrauskopf/ec4eb73c27517ff9c6eb6a90c6e7241f).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer — it's not perfect, sometimes line breaks get dropped, but I found so little information on this maybe it'll help someone.

```
  const parseNode = node => {
    let content = ""

    for (const child of node.childNodes) {
      if (child.tagName === "BR") {
        content += "\n"
      }

      if (child.tagName === "DIV" && !child.querySelector("br")) {
        content += "\n"
      }

      if (child instanceof Text) {
        content += child.textContent
      } else {
        content += parseNode(child)
      }
    }

    return content
  }
```