# Read a multiline contenteditable text in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Let's read a contenteditable element:

```
<span id="myinput" contenteditable="true">This is editable.<br>Yes it is.</span>
```

just after you added manually two white-spaces at the end of the text.

I get :

- `textContent` => `"This is editable.Yes it is.  "`
- `innerText` => `undefined`
- `innerHTML` => `"This is editable.<br>Yes it is. &nbsp;"`
- jQuery `.text()` => same than `textContent`  i.e. line breaks are lost

**How to get `"This is editable.\n Yes it is.  "`?**  (Of course some regex could work on innerHTML, but that's dirty : maybe there are lots of things that I should parse...)

Comment: If there's no simple way, it looks like a job for a _TreeWalker_

Comment: I think there is no other way but using regex, there is are some nice answer here for the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959415/jquery-javascript-regex-replace-br-with-n